# MySQL JOIN two tables with different number of rows by id

Tags: sql, select, join

I have two tables.

```
Table 1

+----+--------+
| Id | Column |
+----+--------+
|  1 |     23 |
+----+--------+
|  2 |     34 |
+----+--------+
|  3 |     99 |
+----+--------+

Table 2

+----+--------+
| Id | Column |
+----+--------+
| 10 |      1 |
+----+--------+
| 11 |      1 |
+----+--------+
| 21 |      2 |
+----+--------+
| 33 |      3 |
+----+--------+
```

I want to combine these tables to get

```
Table 3 (Desired)

+--------+--------+
| Column | Column |
+--------+--------+
|     10 |     23 |
+--------+--------+
|     11 |     23 |
+--------+--------+
|     21 |     34 |
+--------+--------+
|     33 |     99 |
+--------+--------+
```

I know how to get this:

```
Table 3 (Actual)

+--------+--------+
| Column | Column |
+--------+--------+
|     10 |     23 |
+--------+--------+
|     11 |   null |
+--------+--------+
|     21 |     34 |
+--------+--------+
|     33 |     99 |
+--------+--------+
```

but when the rows have duplicate Id columns, the first is the correct value and
the rest are always NULL.

The query I have to produce Table 3 is

```sql
SELECT table2.id, table1.Column 
FROM table2 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT .... ) as table1 ON table1.id = table2.Column
```

How can I join tables to get the correct version of Table 3?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please specify the RDBMS that you are targeting by adding the appropriate tag (Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL, etc.). There may be answers that take advantage of language or product features that are not universally supported. Also, by tagging it with a specific RDBMS, your question may receive attention from people better suited to answer it.

Comment: In your desired result: shouldn't the row `10 -------- 23` be `11 -------- 23`

Comment: For me your query works fine. NULL value shows, that Table2 has a row with ID = 10 and Column = value that not exists in Table1.ID

Comment: I make mistake it has by 11 -------- 23 11 -------- 23

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work fine:

```
SELECT 
  t2.id     AS column1,
  t1.column AS column2
FROM table2 AS t2
LEFT JOIN table1 AS t1 ON t1.id = t2.column;
```

See it in action here:

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bdeac/3)

This will give you the same result you want:

```
| COLUMN1 | COLUMN2 |
---------------------
|      10 |      23 |
|      11 |      23 |
|      21 |      34 |
|      33 |      99 |
```